# SQL subquery calculating to maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple subqueries which i am trying to return as a percentage (maximum 100) and then creating a total average at the end. The problem i am having is returning a maximum of 100 for each subquery. Example query is...

```
, ((  SELECT        SUM((eo.value) / 550) * 100

      FROM          users u1
      INNER JOIN    field_user pu1
      ON            pu1.field_target    = u1.personid
) +
```

So if eo.value is more than 550 then my result will be greater than 100. How can i limit the maximum value to 100?

Comment: Don't tag products not involved... Are you really using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like

```
SELECT SUM(IF(eo.value > 550, 1, (eo.value) / 550)) * 100 AS percent
```

So if the eo.value > 550, it will return 1. So the final percentage will not go beyond 100

Answer (score 0):

Use case statement along with your select.

Ex:

```
  , ((  SELECT        CASE WHEN (SUM((eo.value) / 550) * 100) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE (SUM((eo.value) / 550) * 100) END
     FROM          users u1
     INNER JOIN    field_user pu1
     ON            pu1.field_target    = u1.personid
    ) +
```

Comment: That is not more than a comment.

Comment: And perhaps a case expression would be better?